# Кнопка поверх TableView в Swift

Tags: ios, swift, button, tableview

Всем привет, столкнулся со следующей проблемой. Работаю над приложением которое уже написано под Андройд, и там есть экран на котором пользователь выбирает фильтры поиска(картинку прикреплю). Так вот, так есть кнопка "подтвердить". Эта кнопка не скролится вместе со всеми элементами, но при этом находится поверх них. Так вот, если реализовывать список фильтров с помощью TableView, то как мне разместить кнопку поверх всех ячеек. Заранее спасибо)[image: вот эта кнопка(красная)]

Comment: сделать ее сабвью корневого вью и тогда она никакого отношения к таблице и ее скролу иметь не будет

Comment: Это делается только через код, или можно как-то в сториборде?

Comment: @AndrewGurew можете как в коде, так и в интерфейс билдере.

Comment: @VAndrJ если я запихиваю вьюху как дочку tableview то она просто закрепляется в шапке и никуда не двигается, т.е поверх не становится

Comment: @AndrewGurew добавляйте не на tableview, а на view

Comment: @VAndrJ у tableviewсontroller нет view

Comment: @AndrewGurew с этого нужно было начинать. Добавил 2 варианта.

Answer (score 2):

Вариант первый - использовать `container view`, где `embed segue` к Вашему `UITableViewController`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Вариант второй - простой `UITableView`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]